# Rate of expected value of $\mathcal{O}_p$

Tags: convergence, asymptotics

This is certainly very basic but what is the rate of the expected value of a random variable that is bounded in probability. For example, let $X_n = \mathcal{O}_p (a_n)$ is it true that $\mathbb{E} [X_n] = \mathcal{O}(a_n)$?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In short, no it is not true. You can look for an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477942/does-convergence-in-probability-implies-convergence-of-the-mean).

What you are trying to show is that convergence in probability implies convergence in mean, which is not true. The opposite however is true. If
 $$E(X_n) = \mathcal{O}(a_n) \Rightarrow E\left(\dfrac{X_n}{a_n} - c'\right) \to 0,$$

where $c'$ is a constant, which is convergence in mean, then

$$ X_n = \mathcal{O}(a_n) \Rightarrow \dfrac{X_n}{a_n} \overset{p}{\to} c, $$

where $c$ is some constant. This direction is valid. The direction you are hypothesizing is only true if $\{X_n\}$ is uniformly integrable, as the link above explains.

Comment: Thanks a lot Greenparker! Good point. What do you think about this problem [link] (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207762/asymptotic-normality-and-rate-of-convergence-of-the-mean)